# Paypal error Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal's REST API from my .Net MVC 4 Razor website.

On creating a payment I've traced the following request and response through fiddler:

[image]

Can anyone explain what's causing the error please? The transactions amount total and items price is both 0.24 so I can't understand why the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please set price under items as 0.12. You are shipping 2 items for a total amount of 0.24 so it should have be 0.24 / 2 = 0.12. Assuming the unit price is 0.12, You have correctly set the total amount  as 0.24

Comment: How would I have to deal with a discounted cart amount? So each item i.e. costs 20,- but there is a discount of 2,- on the cart's total? So the sum of the items is not the same as the total.